# cannot recognize epoch time when trying to copy from kafka to vertica

Tags: apache-kafka, epoch, vertica

I am trying to copy a JSON data from Kafka to vertica. I am using the following query

```
COPY public.from_kafka 
   SOURCE KafkaSource(stream='example_data|0|-2, example_data|1|-2',
                      brokers='kafka01.example.com:9092',
                      duration=interval '10000 milliseconds') PARSER KafkaJSONParser()
   REJECTED DATA AS TABLE public.rejections;
```

each message in the topic looks like that:

```
{"location_id":30277, "start_date":1667911800000}
```

when I am running the query, no new rows are created. when I am checking the `rejections` table I see the following `rejected_reason`:

```
Missing or null value for column with NOT NULL constraint [start_date]
```

however the `rejected_data` is `{"location_id":30277, "start_date":1667911800000}`

why does Vertica not recognize the `start_date` field and how can I solve it?

vertica table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.from_kafka
(
    location_id int NOT NULL,
    start_date timestamp NOT NULL
)


CREATE PROJECTION public.from_kafka /*+createtype(L)*/ 
(
 location_id ENCODING RLE,
 start_date ENCODING GCDDELTA
)
AS
 SELECT from_kafka.location_id,
        from_kafka.start_date,
 FROM public.from_kafka
 ORDER BY from_kafka.start_date,
          from_kafka.location_id
SEGMENTED BY hash(from_kafka.location_id, from_kafka.start_date) ALL NODES KSAFE 1;
```

***EDIT - SOLUTION***

`PARSER KafkaJSONParser()` does not know how to convert long into timestamp, due to that I had to convert the JSON message with java, insert the updated JSON to a new topic and then use `KafkaJSONParser()` function

Comment: can you run a `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','public.from_kafka',FALSE)` for us? Just to verify the data type used for `start_date` in the table. A conversion error could lead to a NULL value

Comment: I added the table creation query

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp, in any SQL database, is a timestamp, not an integer.

To load your JSON format and have a timestamp, redefine your table to receive an integer and convert it to a timestamp on the fly.

I do it from file, here, but it will work with a Kafka stream, too.

```
-- create your table like so:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.from_kafka;
CREATE TABLE public.from_kafka
(
    location_id int NOT NULL,
    start_date  int NOT NULL,
    start_date_ts timestamp DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP(start_date//1000)
);
```

This is the JSON file I use:

```bash
$ cat kafka.json
{"location_id":30277, "start_date":1667911800000},
{"location_id":30278, "start_date":1667911900000},
{"location_id":30279, "start_date":1667912000000},
{"location_id":30280, "start_date":1667912100000},
{"location_id":30281, "start_date":1667912200000},
{"location_id":30282, "start_date":1667912300000}
```

And this is the copy command I use:

```
COPY public.from_kafka (
  location_id
, start_date 
)
FROM LOCAL 'kafka.json' PARSER FJsonParser(record_terminator=E'\n')                                                                                                                  
EXCEPTIONS 'kafka.log';
```

And this, finally, is what `from_kafka` will contain:

```
SELECT * FROM public.from_kafka;
-- out  location_id | start_date |    start_date_ts    
-- out -------------+------------+---------------------
-- out        30277 | 1667911800 | 2022-11-08 13:50:00
-- out        30278 | 1667911900 | 2022-11-08 13:51:40
-- out        30279 | 1667912000 | 2022-11-08 13:53:20
-- out        30280 | 1667912100 | 2022-11-08 13:55:00
-- out        30281 | 1667912200 | 2022-11-08 13:56:40
-- out        30282 | 1667912300 | 2022-11-08 13:58:20
```